# Android add editText proggramatically onClick

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layoutparams

so I know the onClick part is quite useless, but just in case it does change anything, ive put it there. so ive got the onClick, and I would like it to add the editText to the current activity, which is called activity_calculation.
I currently have this code which I got from another question :

```
public void addCalc(View view){

EditText myEditText = new EditText(context); // Pass it an Activity or Context
        myEditText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT,WRAP_CONTENT)); // Pass two args; must be LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, or an integer pixel value.
        activity_calculation.addView(myEditText);

    }
```

any help would be appreciated. maybe you can see what ive done wrong

Comment: Why you are creating in onClick.... You Hide the edit text and change visibility during onClick Also... Which might be easy.... You Can Consider That too... If possible

Comment: @MaharithAdityaSS I use onClick because I need the user to add edit texts as much as he needs, its not a set amount, where I can change the visibility, if u understand what I mean...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android adding textview programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730618/android-adding-textview-programatically)

Answer (score 2):

First get a reference to the activity's root layout. To do this add an id attribute to your activity layout file's root layout. eg :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="+id/rootLayout" />
```

Then, get a reference to it and add the created EditText.

```
//If your root layout is a RelativeLayout, use that instead
LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
EditText myEditText = new EditText(rootView.getContext()); 
myEditText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT,WRAP_CONTENT)); 
rootView.addView(myEditText);
```

Comment: what exactly should go in the parenthesis that says context

Comment: Try rootView.getContext()

Comment: don't think you can do this, tried it now, but its marked as error, I'm newbie, but I think its coz the rootview is only given a value later on in the block

Comment: Edited to fix this .

Comment: that seems to do the trick thanks. ive got one last problem, my `addView` is in red, ive imported the editText widget. not sure where this problem rises from

Comment: Edited again, forgot about this

Comment: this works great, needs a few tweaks, but for its purpose, its great. thnks